# C# Windows Forms ComboBox DropDown does not highlight selected item when DroppedDown=true

Tags: c#, combobox, dropdown

I have a ComboBox with DataBinding and I can use a BindingSource and the SelectedValue and SelectedIndex properties to select an Item.  I know my SelectedItem is actually *selected* because it is properly highlighted if I drop down the list by clicking the DropDown icon.

However, if execute the code `comboBox1.DroppedDown = true;`, the SelectedItem is Not Highlighed like it would be if I drop down the list by clicking the icon.

I want to highlight the SelectedItem in a DataBound ComboBox DropDown list when I programmatically set `comboBox1.DroppedDown = true;`

What is the best way to Select an Item before or after `.DroppedDown=true' and then Highlight the SelectedItem in the dropped down list?

Comment: Make sure the control is selected/focused, call `ComboBox1.Select();` before calling `.DroppedDown = true;`

Comment: Something like `comboBox1.PerformClick();` or `comboBox1.HideSelection=false;` would do the trick... but only in my imagination.

Comment: `comboBox1.Select();` did not have any affect. My `comboBox1.DroppedDown=true;` is executed in the `comboBox1.TextChanged` event handler. If I press the DownArrow key after the TextChanged event concludes, and I can see the DropDown list, then it properly highlights the SelectedItem.  Unfortunately `comboBox1.DroppedDown=true; SendKeys.Send("{DOWN}");` in the TextChanged event handler works a little, but has kinks in it.

Comment: *JQSOFT* - I actually think the problem is related to the Dropped Down List not having focus. However, I cannot find a method for setting the list's focus other than clicking the DropDown Icon or sending a Up/Down arrow key after the list is dropped down. The SendKeys method is not a viable solution, however, it does show the problem is a bug in the ComboBox implementation and not the code setting the SelectedItem or turning the Cursor back on after `comboBox1.DroppedDown=true;`

Comment: No, if there is a selected item then it will be highlighted even if the control is not selected or focused. My first comment is _Just In Case_ suggestion. Check your code and find where the selection is cleared. Just tested with and without binding source, with `ComboBoxStyle.DropDown` and `ComboBoxStyle.DropDownList` and it works as it should.

Comment: ...and please prepend a name with `@` to notify someone.

Comment: @JQSOFT - Thanks for the notify tip! The *simple* scenario using the Items prepopulated in the VS designer and setting AutoCompleteMode to "Suggest" works close to how I want the DataBound method to work. I think the focus is lost when the "suggestion" changes and then Selects its portion of the Text. If I watch very carefully, I see the SelectedItem highlighted in the list for a fraction of a second before it is cleared.  When I use the "DrawItem" method, I can draw the e.Index= bindingSource.Position (the SelectedItem) but, I cannot control Redrawing a previous Item when the Item is changed.

Comment: To continue my previous comment... I can *redraw* the drop down items with DrawItem by hovering the mouse over them.  This preserves my SelectedItem highlighted drawing and clears the *highlight* from the *stale* items.  I tried things like `((ListBox)comboBox1.Invalidate(true);` with no luck.

Comment: Another hint buddy. The auto complete drop down and the combo box drop down are different windows. You don't have control over the first one. When you type something in the edit, the matches are listed and displayed in the auto complete window. Then if there is 100% match, it becomes the `SelectedItem` and the control switch back to the combo box drop down showing you that new selection.

Comment: Everything works as @JQSOFT described. Except the SelectedItem is not highlighed in the DropDown list if I dropped it down using `DroppedDown=true;` If I click on the dropdown icon, it works and highlights the SelectedItem OK. I think it is a problem similar to the cursor disappearing after `DroppedDown=true;` I think it is a bug because I see no reason to hide the Cursor and SelectedItem from the user when programming the drop down action instead of requiring the user to click the icon.  All the method needs to do is a `comboBoxButton.PerformClick();` action, and all will work fine.

Comment: *Following up* - I was unable to solve this problem and decided to write my own component to replace the ComboBox in my applications. When I get some slack time, I will submit 2 bug reports to Microsoft for the databinding lost highlight/focus and disappearing cursor issues and post back the results.